# How is LINQ compiled into the CIL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, compiler-construction, cil

For example:

```
var query = from c in db.Cars select c;
foreach(Car aCar in query)
{
     Console.WriteLine(aCar.Name);
}
```

How would this translate once it is compiled? What happens behind the scenes?

Comment: I assume that this is a LINQ-to-SQL query, rather than just a filter on a collection?  The former will be doing a lot more work behind the scenes than the latter, obviously.

Comment: Actually, let's go for a LINQ-to-Objects filter on a collection.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is compiled in the following way:

1. First, the LINQ query expression is transformed into method calls:

   ```
   public static void Main()
   {
       var query = db.Cars.Select<Car, Car>(c => c);
       foreach (Car aCar in query)
       {
            Console.WriteLine(aCar.Name);
       }
   }
   ```
2. If `db.Cars` is of type `IEnumerable<Car>` (which it is for LINQ-to-Objects), then the lambda expression is turned into a separate method:

   ```
   private Car lambda0(Car c)
   {
       return c;
   }
   private Func<Car, Car> CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1;
   public static void Main()
   {
       if (CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 == null)
           CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = new Func<Car, Car>(lambda0);
       var query = db.Cars.Select<Car, Car>(CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1);
       foreach // ...
   }
   ```

   In reality the method is not called `lambda0` but something like `<Main>b__0` (where `Main` is the name of the containing method). Similarly, the cached delegate is actually called `CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1`.

   If you are using LINQ-to-SQL, then `db.Cars` will be of type `IQueryable<Car>` and this step is very different. It would instead turn the lambda expression into an expression tree:

   ```
   public static void Main()
   {
       var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Car), "c");
       var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Car, Car>>(parameter, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }));
       var query = db.Cars.Select<Car, Car>(lambda);
       foreach // ...
   }
   ```
3. The `foreach` loop is transformed into a `try/finally` block (this is the same for both):

   ```
   IEnumerator<Car> enumerator = null;
   try
   {
       enumerator = query.GetEnumerator();
       Car aCar;
       while (enumerator.MoveNext())
       {
           aCar = enumerator.Current;
           Console.WriteLine(aCar.Name);
       }
   }
   finally
   {
       if (enumerator != null)
           ((IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
   }
   ```
4. Finally, this is compiled into IL the expected way. The following is for `IEnumerable<Car>`:

   ```
   // Put db.Cars on the stack
   L_0016: ldloc.0 
   L_0017: callvirt instance !0 DatabaseContext::get_Cars()


   // “if” starts here
   L_001c: ldsfld Func<Car, Car> Program::CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
   L_0021: brtrue.s L_0034
   L_0023: ldnull 
   L_0024: ldftn Car Program::lambda0(Car)
   L_002a: newobj instance void Func<Car, Car>::.ctor(object, native int)
   L_002f: stsfld Func<Car, Car> Program::CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1


   // Put the delegate for “c => c” on the stack
   L_0034: ldsfld Func<Car, Car> Program::CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1


   // Call to Enumerable.Select()
   L_0039: call IEnumerable<!!1> Enumerable::Select<Car, Car>(IEnumerable<!!0>, Func<!!0, !!1>)
   L_003e: stloc.1


   // “try” block starts here
   L_003f: ldloc.1 
   L_0040: callvirt instance IEnumerator<!0> IEnumerable<Car>::GetEnumerator()
   L_0045: stloc.3


   // “while” inside try block starts here
   L_0046: br.s L_005a
   L_0048: ldloc.3   // body of while starts here
   L_0049: callvirt instance !0 IEnumerator<Car>::get_Current()
   L_004e: stloc.2 
   L_004f: ldloc.2 
   L_0050: ldfld string Car::Name
   L_0055: call void Console::WriteLine(string)
   L_005a: ldloc.3   // while condition starts here
   L_005b: callvirt instance bool IEnumerator::MoveNext()
   L_0060: brtrue.s L_0048  // end of while
   L_0062: leave.s L_006e   // end of try


   // “finally” block starts here
   L_0064: ldloc.3 
   L_0065: brfalse.s L_006d
   L_0067: ldloc.3 
   L_0068: callvirt instance void IDisposable::Dispose()
   L_006d: endfinally
   ```

   The compiled code for the `IQueryable<Car>` version is also as expected. Here is the important part that is different from the above (the local variables will have different offsets and names now, but let’s disregard that):

   ```
   // typeof(Car)
   L_0021: ldtoken Car
   L_0026: call Type Type::GetTypeFromHandle(RuntimeTypeHandle)


   // Expression.Parameter(typeof(Car), "c")
   L_002b: ldstr "c"
   L_0030: call ParameterExpression Expression::Parameter(Type, string)
   L_0035: stloc.3 


   // Expression.Lambda(...)
   L_0036: ldloc.3 
   L_0037: ldc.i4.1           // var paramArray = new ParameterExpression[1]
   L_0038: newarr ParameterExpression
   L_003d: stloc.s paramArray
   L_003f: ldloc.s paramArray
   L_0041: ldc.i4.0                    // paramArray[0] = parameter;
   L_0042: ldloc.3 
   L_0043: stelem.ref 
   L_0044: ldloc.s paramArray
   L_0046: call Expression<!!0> Expression::Lambda<Func<Car, Car>>(Expression, ParameterExpression[])


   // var query = Queryable.Select(...);
   L_004b: call IQueryable<!!1> Queryable::Select<Car, Car>(IQueryable<!!0>, Expression<Func<!!0, !!1>>)
   L_0050: stloc.1
   ```

Comment: very good answer! I think step step 2 is the most important one here. For completeness could you add info about where the linq is not in process (like linq2sql perhaps) please?

Comment: @Preet: Not sure what you mean, but I added a note about LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @Preet: I added the complete compilation for LINQ-to-SQL now. :)

Comment: great explanation, but i think you should add description of that Select and other LINQ is implemented via `foreach ... yield return` thus it is not storing collections in memory

Comment: @Andrey: I don’t understand. Nothing in this posting makes any such claim as to what is stored in memory and what isn’t. This posting answers the question, which is *how is the query expression compiled into IL.*

Comment: @Timwi ok, i am just telling how according to my opinion you can make this answer perfect. If you disagree it is up to you :)

Comment: @Timwi, good answer! I have one comment though. In part 1, you write that it's converted into Select<Car, Car>(c => c).
Are you sure it does type inference there? I thought the first step is to only do a "dumb" translation and let the compiler do all the type inference in step 2. So in step 1, it would be the select without the types..

Comment: @Anton: You are right that the type inference is separate from the conversion of LINQ syntax to method syntax. The latter is indeed a “dumb” translation. However, it happens before the stuff that I labeled “step 2”. I just conflated them into one “step”.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile it and run [`ildasm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28VS.80%29.aspx) against the resulting executable to find out.

Comment: I have done this, but I was hoping for a fuller and more detailed explanation. :)

Comment: or use reflector if you want something more userfriendly.